# Moodle database connection failed in local

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I'm trying to install an existing Moodle app in local to develop a child theme, but it appears the following message after configuring `config.php`. I'm not able to be aware of the error. That's my file:

```
<?php
unset($CFG);  // Ignore this line
global $CFG;  // This is necessary here for PHPUnit execution
$CFG = new stdClass();
$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli';      // 'mysqli', 'mariadb', 'mysqli', 'mssql', 'sqlsrv' or 'oci'
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';     // 'native' only at the moment
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';  // eg 'localhost' or 'db.isp.com' or IP
$CFG->dbname    = '(name)';     // database name, eg moodle
$CFG->dbuser    = '(same as above)';   // your database username
$CFG->dbpass    = '(pass)';   // your database password
$CFG->prefix    = 'pztp_';       // prefix to use for all table names
$CFG->dboptions = array(
    'dbpersist' => false,       // should persistent database connections be
                                //  used? set to 'false' for the most stable
                                //  setting, 'true' can improve performance
                                //  sometimes
    'dbsocket'  => false,       // should connection via UNIX socket be used?
                                //  if you set it to 'true' or custom path
                                //  here set dbhost to 'localhost',
                                //  (please note mysql is always using socket
                                //  if dbhost is 'localhost' - if you need
                                //  local port connection use '127.0.0.1')
    'dbport'    => '3306',          // the TCP port number to use when connecting
                                //  to the server. keep empty string for the
                                //  default port
);
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$CFG->dataroot  = 'C:/wamp64/www/example/data';
$CFG->directorypermissions = 02777;
$CFG->admin = 'admin';
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/setup.php'); // Do not edit
```

dbname, dbuser and dbpass are censored due to privacy politics, as well as application name, but two first are the same value and the name of the "root" folder (named example) is given in dataroot path. I've created that user and DB in the DBMS, I've assigned all the privileges to the user for that DB and I've imported the DB. I use PHP 7.0.33 (that can't be updated) due to the Moodle version. I've tried using XAMPP and WAMP with the same result.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try creating a test PHP file - in the Moodle root folder - to test the connection to see if its Moodle or the database.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $dbport);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Thanks! I won't know if it works because I didn't need it by the time you had posted it, but I really appreciate you have spent your time on solving my issue. Thank you a lot!